# MYSQL count all case on a column

Tags: mysql

Here are my table :

```
CREATE TABLE box 
(
  id int,
  fk_type int,
  hasTrackingNb int /*0:No,1:Yes,2:Unreadable */
);

CREATE TABLE box_type
(
  id int,  
  name VARCHAR(50),
  shouldBeTracked int /* 0:No,1:Yes */
);
INSERT INTO `box_type` (`id`, `name`, `shouldBeTracked`) VALUES
(1, 'TrackedBox', 1),
(2, 'NormalBox', 0);
INSERT INTO `box` (`id`, `fk_type`, `hasTrackingNb`) VALUES
(1, 1, 0),
(2, 1, 1),
/*(3, 1, 2),*/
(4, 2, 0),
(5, 2, 0);
```

I want a table like :

```
--------------------
hasTrackingNb | NB |
--------------------
0             |  X |
1             |  Y |
2             |  Z |
```

My current query :

```
select A.hasTrackingNb,COUNT(*) as NB
FROM box A
join box_type B on A.fk_type=B.id
where B.shouldBeTracked=1
group by A.hasTrackingNb
```

Result :

```
--------------------
hasTrackingNb | NB |
--------------------
0             |  1 |
1             |  1 |
```

What should I change on my query to always have the 3 possible states of hasTrackingNb in the result even if 0?

Thanks

Edit 1:
thanks to @Thomas G and @MatBailie I have as query:

```
select J.hasTrackingNb, COUNT(*) as NB
FROM (SELECT 0 hasTrackingNb UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) J
LEFT OUTER JOIN box A ON A.hasTrackingNb=J.hasTrackingNb
LEFT OUTER join box_type B on A.fk_type=B.id and B.shouldBeTracked=1
group by J.hasTrackingNb;
```

which give on sql Fiddle the result:

```
--------------------
hasTrackingNb | NB |
--------------------
0             |  3 |
1             |  1 |
2             |  1 |
```

I was expecting this due to the data in box:

```
--------------------
hasTrackingNb | NB |
--------------------
0             |  1 |
1             |  1 |
2             |  0 |
```

Comment: Add base (SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2), join your data to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With corrections to the answer from @ThomasG , and removing the aliases A and B

***(Aliases should always MEAN something, never use arbitrary letters)***.

```
SELECT
  J.hasTrackingNb,
  COUNT(box_type.id) as NB
FROM
  (SELECT 0 hasTrackingNb UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) J
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  box
    ON  box.hasTrackingNb = J.hasTrackingNb
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  box_type
    ON  box_type.id              = box.fk_type
    AND box_type.shouldBeTracked = 1
GROUP BY
  J.hasTrackingNb;
```

Alternatively, a slightly more explicit answer would be...

```
SELECT
  J.hasTrackingNb,
  COUNT(box.id) as NB
FROM
  (SELECT 0 hasTrackingNb UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) J
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (
    box
  INNER JOIN
    box_type
      ON  box_type.id              = box.fk_type
      AND box_type.shouldBeTracked = 1
  )
    ON box.hasTrackingNb = J.hasTrackingNb
GROUP BY
  J.hasTrackingNb;
```

This has the benefit of being clear as to what you're counting, and that the join on `box_type` is being used to filter results.

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=233ba6a547e2ba0f0c95ae6111ec79f1

Answer (score 0):

Craft a virtual table containing all the values you want always to be listed. UNION is your friend.

```
SELECT 0 hasTrackingNb 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2
```

Gives

| hasTrackingNb |
| --- |
| 0 |
| 1 |
| 2 |

Then you should start your query from this virtual table, and change your joins to LEFT JOIN to always list the values even if there's no match.

```
select J.hasTrackingNb, COUNT(*) as NB
FROM (SELECT 0 hasTrackingNb UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2) J
LEFT JOIN box A ON A.hasTrackingNb=J.hasTrackingNb
LEFT join box_type B on A.fk_type=B.id
group by J.hasTrackingNb;
```

Comment: `COUNT()` never returns `NULL`, no need for `COALESCE()`. Also, `COUNT(*)` returns `1` even when there are no records from `B` successfully joined. It should be `COUNT(B.id)`, as in that form NULLs are ignored, thus will return `0`.

Comment: You're also missing `B.shouldBeTracked=1` which the OP has in the `WHERE` clause and you need in the last join's predicate.

Comment: As @MatBailie said in the previous comment, your query work only if `where B.shouldBeTracked=1` is missing. If I add it I have the same result as my original query

Comment: @CLUB_RI And as I also said, in this case you Do Not put it in the where clause, you put it in the join predicate. Where clauses are applied After the joins, so your "correction" undid exactly what the LEFT JOIN had accomplished. You need `LEFT JOIN box_type B on A.fk_type=B.id AND B.shouldBeTracked=1`

Comment: @MatBailie Thanks for the precision. I'll edit my original post with the update result as it is not what I was expecting

Comment: @Club_RI - As per my first comment, it should be `COUNT(B.id)` and not `COUNT(*)`